# Android Logcat Error Interpretation

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am developing an android app where the user has to rester his details to the server....
The user(here student) has to give his roll no, name, branch, semester.The code has no syntax error but the code is not uploading the details to the server....

```
package com.example.collegenoticeboard;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.example.testproject3.R;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewRegister extends Activity
{
Button b;
EditText et,et_name,et_rollno;
TextView tv2;
HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
int s_id,b_id,ba_id,d_id;

String sem,s_sem,s_br,s_div,s_bch;

RadioGroup rg_semester;
RadioButton     rb_semester1,rb_semester2,rb_semester3,rb_semester4,rb_semester5,rb_semester6,rb_semester7,rb_semester8;

RadioGroup rg_branch;
RadioButton rb_branch_it,rb_branch_comps,rb_branch_mech,rb_branch_extc,rb_branch_etrx;

RadioGroup rg_division;
RadioButton rb_division_a,rb_division_b;

RadioGroup rg_batch;
RadioButton rb_batch1,rb_batch2,rb_batch3,rb_batch4;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    try{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newregister);

    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ntv1);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newsubmit);

    et_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.to_name);

    et_rollno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.to_rollno);

    rg_semester = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupSemester);
    //s_id = rg_semester.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb_semester1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_01);
    rb_semester2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_02);
    rb_semester3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_03);
    rb_semester4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_04);
    rb_semester5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_05);
    rb_semester6=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_06);
    rb_semester7=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_07);
    rb_semester8=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_sem_08);

    rg_branch = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBranch);
    //b_id = rg_branch.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb_branch_it=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_br_it);
    rb_branch_comps=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_br_ce);
    rb_branch_mech=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_br_me);
    rb_branch_extc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_br_extc);
    rb_branch_etrx=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_br_exe);

    rg_division = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupDivision);
    //d_id = rg_division .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb_division_a=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_div_a);
    rb_division_b=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_div_b);

    rg_batch = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupBatch);
    //ba_id = rg_batch .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    rb_batch1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_batch_1);
    rb_batch2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_batch_2);
    rb_batch3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_batch_3);
    rb_batch4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_batch_4);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            final ProgressDialog p = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext()).show(v.getContext(),"Waiting for Server", "Accessing Server");
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override

                public void run() 
                {                   
                     try
                     {
                         //tv2.setText("Harsh");
                        /* rb_semester  = (RadioButton) findViewById(s_id);
                         rb_branch  = (RadioButton) findViewById(b_id);
                         rb_division  = (RadioButton) findViewById(d_id);
                         rb_batch  = (RadioButton) findViewById(ba_id);*/
                         tv2.setText("smester1");
                         if(rb_semester1.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester1.getText();
                         }

                         if(rb_semester2.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester2.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester3.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester3.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester4.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester4.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester5.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester5.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester6.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester6.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester7.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_sem=(String) rb_semester7.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_semester8.isChecked())
                         {
                              s_sem=(String) rb_semester8.getText();
                         }


                         if(rb_branch_it.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_br=(String) rb_branch_it.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_branch_comps.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_br=(String) rb_branch_comps.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_branch_mech.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_br=(String) rb_branch_mech.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_branch_extc.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_br=(String) rb_branch_extc.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_branch_etrx.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_br=(String) rb_branch_etrx.getText();
                         }
                         //tv2.setText(s_sem+s_br);

                         if(rb_division_a.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_div=(String) rb_division_a.getText();
                         }
                         if(rb_division_b.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_div=(String) rb_division_b.getText();
                         }
                         //tv2.setText(s_sem+s_br+s_div);

                         if(rb_batch1.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_bch=(String) rb_batch1.getText();
                         }

                         if(rb_batch2.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_bch=(String) rb_batch2.getText();
                         }

                         if(rb_batch3.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_bch=(String) rb_batch3.getText();
                         }

                         if(rb_batch4.isChecked())
                         {
                             s_bch=(String) rb_batch4.getText();
                         }


                         httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                         httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/test22.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
                         //add your data
                         nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                         // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",et_name.getText().toString().trim()));
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rollno",et_rollno.getText().toString().trim()));
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("semester",s_sem));
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch",s_br));
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("division",s_div));
                         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("batch",s_bch));



                         //tv2.setText(s_sem+s_br+s_div+s_bch);
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                         //Execute HTTP Post Request
                         response=httpclient.execute(httppost);


                         ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                         final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                         System.out.println("Response : " + response);

                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                         {
                                public void run() 
                                {
                                    p.dismiss();

                                    tv2.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                                }
                         });

                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {

                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                         {
                            public void run() 
                            {
                                p.dismiss();
                            }
                         });
                         System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
                     }
                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }
    });

}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }

}


}
```

Here is the log cat error:

```
03-30 10:11:40.567: E/Trace(733): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: what is Response from PHP?

Comment: Did you add appropriate permissions(such as accessing files) to your manifest file?

Comment: @AndroidDev: NO response.

Comment: @ABFORCE: All required Persmissions are taken.

Comment: Please attach your complete LogCat. The one that you have mentioned is not really the error. There must be something else going on.